# type of params of function which also is a param?

Tags: typescript

NOTE: I use `"strictFunctionTypes": true` option.

I want to type the arguments of a wrapper function, which accepts a single function and rest params to be passed to the accepted function.

I think showing code might be easier:

```
const call = function(func, restParams) { // ← How to type this?
  return func(...restParams);
}

const logAltForm = function(numParam: number, strParam: string) {
  console.log(numParam.toExponential(), strParam.toUpperCase());
}

call(logAltForm, ['a', 5]); // ... to avoid the runtime error here?
```

How should I type the parameters of `call`, that is, `func` and `restParams` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type it similar to the normal `call` method on functions:

```
const call = function<Args extends any[], Res>(
  func: (...args: Args) => Res,
  restParams: Args,
) {
  return func(...restParams)
}
```